# Why is binary search O(log n), when it runs 4 times?

Tags: algorithm, search, time-complexity, binary-search

I saw some videos about O(log n) time complexity,
but then I tried a couple of binary search method on the Internet tutorial,
and I am more confused now.

> In computer science, big O notation is used to classify algorithms according to how their running time or space requirements grow as the input size grows.

An example binary search:
https://jsfiddle.net/Hoyly/mhynk7gp/3/

```js
function binarySearch(sortedArray, key){
    let start = 0;
    let end = sortedArray.length - 1;

    while (start <= end) {
        let middle = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);
                console.log('count',++count,sortedArray[middle]);
        if (sortedArray[middle] === key) {
            return middle;
        } else if (sortedArray[middle] < key) {
            start = middle + 1;
        } else {
            end = middle - 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
let count= 0;
console.log('first 1:');
let res1 = binarySearch([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],8);
console.log('first 2:');
let res2 = binarySearch([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],1);
console.log('answer:',res1,res2);
```

As you can see in the jsfiddle

#### If I try to find "1" in 8-length array

1. The method calling count is **3**
2. 2^3 = 8
3. It is how people call it is a O(log n) function

#### But If I try to find "8"

1. The calling count is **4**
2. 2^4 != 8
3. It is definitely not O(log n) definition from the worst case

Comment: You can easily understand that `log(n)` is some approximation of the "calling count": what if `n=7` ?? And what if the element you are looking for is `sortedArray[(start + end)/2]` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binary search here can do one extra step depending on which half of the array you are searching in. If it used `Math.ceil` instead of `Math.floor` then `8` would be found in three steps, while `1` would be found in four.

If we expand this to 128 items, then the last item would be found in 7 or 8 steps (again, depending on which half). In general, the real worst case for the steps taken would be `log n + 1`. However, for big O, we do not consider the constants, only the growth rate of the function. `O(log n + 1)` simplifies to `O(log n)`. The same way how `O(2n)` is still `O(n)`.

Answer (score 2):

The time complexity is O(log *n*), not log *n* without the big O. I won't explain the full meaning of big-O here; see the [definition on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) for that.

Suffice to say that it only gives an *upper bound* on the *growth rate* of the runtime as *n* grows, and only when *n* is big enough. Even if *n* = 8 resulted in 1000 calls, the algorithm could still be O(log *n*).

Comment: I am not sure that your explanation with 1000 calls is enlightening...